# PC BSODing for no reason (Intel Graphics)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod, intel-graphics

I am using a Windows 7 PC and I am trying to play Garry's Mod. This PC used to BSOD ALL the time, but only because drivers were missing, but I got them updated and installed. So today, I installed Garry's Mod since it's one of my favorite games. Anyway, I had set ALL settings to the lowest. It's not a bad PC, I just like running it really fast in a higher resolution (1280x720, or 720p). I accidentally clicked the quote ( this -> ` ) key. Garry's Mod crashes, but the PC is still running (no BSOD). I restart the game, but it just crashes on load. So I check the settings, all are on highest. I turn them all down to the lowest this time. However, this time, instead of just crashing Garry's Mod, it crashed igdkmd32.sys, as if the drivers were gone again.

I thought this was strange, cause the drivers are u-t-d (up-to-date), and the PC had no other applications open. Here's the weird thing. I have a even lower end PC that plays it full speed. (low settings tho).

Here's the specs of both:

nice PC (one with BSOD):
Intel Core 2 Duo E7400 running at 2.80 GHz;
4.00GB of RAM (DDR2);
no graphics card (no PCI slots);
Intel Integrated Graphics (Q45);

lower end PC (one that needs all low settings and low res): 
Intel Core 2 Duo running at 3.00GHz (not sure of model no.);
2.00GB of RAM (had 4 GB, but somethings wrong with two 1GB sticks);
no graphics card (PCI slots, but hard to find for 2.75 inch PCI slot);
Intel Integrated Graphics (Q45);

They're basically the same PC, but one has 2GB less RAM. All (Graphics) drivers are the same for the two PCs. I'll upload the Minidump if that helps at all. https://parappawithfries.com/minidump/040319-21262-01.dmp

Comment: memtest says everything's ok? Not many other parts to try swapping out / testing.

Comment: how do I do memtest? cmd - memtest?

Comment: I run memtest (memtest86 I think) from live Linux iso's (usb/dvd), but it has it's own iso's too. Apparently windows has it's own memory tester somewhere in the control panel also. Found [this link](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/check-for-bad-memory/) from a quick search.

Comment: oh. RAMs fine. You can see from diagnostic tool

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/kgub1ir

Comment: windbg is very help in a case like this in order to analyze the dump file

Comment: I use BlueScreenView (NirSoft)

Comment: So windows memory tester, or memtest, did at least one full "pass" or "test"? That image says it was only 6% complete, and you already had two bad ram sticks, I'd still suspect the other two sticks, especially if they're all from the same source

Comment: The PC that is BSODing is a OEM PC. Also, I let it get to 100%. No issues.